# Ruby script on-all-nodes-run not only for teaching

Tags: ruby, multithreading, networking, child-process

I wrote the following Ruby script several years ago and have been using it often ever since on a Bioinformatics computer cluster.

It pulls out a list of hosts from the Torque queuing system `qnodes`. It `ssh`'es and runs a command on all the nodes. Then it prints the output and/or errors in a defined order (alphabetical sort of the hostnames).

A nice feature: results are printed immediately for the host that is next in the order.

[image: on-all-nodes-run]

I would like to use it as an example for a Ruby workshop. Could you please suggest best-practice and design pattern improvements?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

EXCLUDE = [/girkelab/, /biocluster/, /parrot/, /owl/] 

require "open3"

# Non-interactive, no password asking, and seasonable timeouts
SSH_OPTIONS = ["-o PreferredAuthentications=publickey,hostbased,gssapi,gssapi-with-mic",
               "-o ForwardX11=no",
               "-o BatchMode=yes",
               "-o SetupTimeOut=5",
               "-o ServerAliveInterval=5",
               "-o ServerAliveCountMax=2"
              ].join(" ")

SSH    = "/usr/bin/ssh #{SSH_OPTIONS}"
MKDIR  = "/bin/mkdir"

raise "Pleae give this command at least one argument" if ARGV.size < 1
COMMAND = ARGV[0..-1].join(' ')

output_o = {}
output_e = {}


IO_CONNECTIONS_TO_REMOTE_PROCESSES = {}

def on_all_nodes(&block)
  nodes = []
  Kernel.open('|qnodes | grep -v "^ " | grep -v "^$"') do |f|
    while line = f.gets
      i = line.split(' ').first
      nodes.push(i) if EXCLUDE.select{|x| i =~ x}.empty?
    end
  end
  nodes.sort.each {|n| block.call(n)}
end


# Create processes
on_all_nodes do |node|
  stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("#{SSH} #{node} \"#{COMMAND}\"")
  IO_CONNECTIONS_TO_REMOTE_PROCESSES[node] = [stdin, stdout, stderr]
end


has_remote_errors = false

# Collect results
on_all_nodes do |node|
  stdin, stdout, stderr = IO_CONNECTIONS_TO_REMOTE_PROCESSES[node]

  stdin.close

  e_thread = Thread.new do
    while line = stderr.gets
      line.chomp!
      STDERR.puts "#{node} ERROR: #{line}"
      has_remote_errors = true
    end
  end

  o_thread = Thread.new do
    while line = stdout.gets
      line.chomp!
      puts "#{node}      : #{line}"
    end
  end

  # Let the threads finish
  t1 = nil
  t2 = nil
  while [t1, t2].include? nil
    if t1.nil?
      t1 = e_thread.join(0.1) # Gives 1/10 of a second to STDERR
    end
    if t2.nil?
      t2 = o_thread.join(0.1) # Give 1/10 of a second to STDOUT
    end
  end

end


exit(1) if has_remote_errors
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, take a look at the [`Net::SSH`](http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v2/api/index.html) library. I don't have much experience with it, so I don't know whether it supports all the options you need. But if it does, using it might be more robust than using the command line utility (you wouldn't have to worry about whether `ssh` is installed in the place you expect (or at all) and you wouldn't have to worry about escaping the arguments).

Assuming you can't (or won't) use `Net::SSH`, you should at least replace `/usr/bin/ssh` with just `ssh`, so at least it still works if `ssh` is installed in another location in the PATH.

---

```
nodes = []
Kernel.open('|qnodes | grep -v "^ " | grep -v "^$"') do |f|
  while line = f.gets
    i = line.split(' ').first
    nodes.push(i) if EXCLUDE.select{|x| i =~ x}.empty?
  end
end
```

1. When you initialize an empty array and then append to it in a loop, that is often a good sign you want to use `map` and/or `select` instead.
2. `line = f.gets` is a bit of an anti-pattern in ruby. The `IO` class already has methods to iterate a file line-wise.
3. To find out whether none of the elements in an array meet a condition, negating `any?` seems more idiomatic than building an array with `select` and check whether it's empty.

   ```
   nodes = Kernel.open('|qnodes | grep -v "^ " | grep -v "^$"') do |f|
     f.lines.map do |line|
       line.split(' ').first
     end.reject do |i|
       EXCLUDE.any? {|x| i =~ x}
     end
   end
   ```

---

```
nodes.sort.each {|n| block.call(n)}
```

I would recommend that instead of taking a block and yielding each element, you just return `nodes.sort` and rename the function to `all_nodes`. This way you can use `all_nodes.each` to execute code on all nodes, but you could also use `all_nodes.map` or `all_nodes.select` when it makes sense.

---

```
Open3.popen3("#{SSH} #{node} \"#{COMMAND}\"")
```

Note that this will break if `COMMAND` contains double quotes itself. Generally trying to escape command line arguments by surrounding them with quotes is a bad idea. `system` and `open3` accept multiple arguments exactly to avoid this.

If you make `SSH` an array (with one element per argument) instead of a string, you can use the multiple-arguments version of `popen3` and can thus avoid the fickle solution of adding quote around `COMMAND` to escape spaces, i.e.:

```
Open3.popen3(*(SSH + [node, COMMAND]))
```

---

```
IO_CONNECTIONS_TO_REMOTE_PROCESSES = {}
# ...
on_all_nodes do |node|
  stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("#{SSH} #{node} \"#{COMMAND}\"")
  IO_CONNECTIONS_TO_REMOTE_PROCESSES[node] = [stdin, stdout, stderr]
end
```

If you heeded my above advice about `all_nodes` you can simplify this using `map`. I also would suggest not using a Hash here. If you use an array instead, the nodes will stay in the order in which you inserted them, which will mean that you can iterate over that array instead of invoking `all_nodes` again.

```
has_remote_errors = false

all_nodes.map do |node|
  [node, Open3.popen3(*(SSH + [node, COMMAND]))]
end.each do |node, (stdin, stdout, stderr)|
  stdin.close

  ethread = # ...
  # ...
end
```

This way you removed the complexity of first putting everything into a hash and then getting it out again.

---

```
while line = stderr.gets
```

Again, this can be written more idiomatically as `stderr.each_line do |line|`. Same with stdout.

---

```
first = true
```

This is never used. I can only assume that it's a left over of previous iterations of the code, which is no longer necessary. Obviously it should be removed.

---

```
# Let the threads finish
t1 = nil
t2 = nil
while [t1, t2].include? nil
  if t1.nil?
    t1 = e_thread.join(0.1) # Gives 1/10 of a second to STDERR
  end
  if t2.nil?
    t2 = o_thread.join(0.1) # Give 1/10 of a second to STDOUT
  end
end
```

I don't see any benefit of doing it this way. Just do:

```
e_thread.join
o_thread.join
```

Note that `join`ing on one thread does not mean that the other threads stop running - only the main thread does, but that's perfectly okay as you want that anyway.

Comment: `e_thread.join; o_thread.join` works just fine. I am not able to reproduce nether dead-locks nor the out-of-order problems. This alone cuts 10 lines.

Answer (score 3):

One can also use the '[parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel)' gem to similar effect:

```
host_hash = { "hosta" => {}, "hostb" => {} }     
Parallel.each(host_hash.keys, :in_threads => host_hash.keys.size) do |host|

  cmd = "ssh #{host} whoami"  # assuming keys are setup.
  Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    host_hash[host]['stdout'] = stdout.read
    host_hash[host]['stderr'] = stderr.read
    host_hash[host]['exit_code'] = wait_thr.value
    if wait_thr.value != 0
      $stderr.puts "ssh #{host} failed with #{wait_thr.value}"
    end
  end
end
# then loop through hash to see results.
```

The one issue I see is that you have to wait for the SSH commands to complete before you see any output. There may be a way to '[stream](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/ruby-subprocesses-with-stdout-stderr-streams.html)' the output as it happens.